# vim not drawn correctly in tmux

Tags: vim, statusbar, tmux, vim-powerline, ctrlp

I've got some issues with vim in tmux. It is not drawn correctly. I think that the statusbar introduced by tmux messes with the way vim draws its layout.
When I create two windows, open vim in one of them and switch to the other one and then back to vim, I see this:

[image: Image of double tmux statusbar]

Also, CtrlP behaves weird. It looks like this when I fire it up:

[image: CtrlP drawn wrong]

The VIM statusbar is obviously not drawn in this picture. It should be above the CtrlP menu.

The system with this bad behaviour is a debian installation (actually in a chroot inside archlinux). Here is a bit of info about the system and the vim and tmux versions.

```
(precise32)root@excalibur:llvm-apps# uname -a[5/5]
Linux excalibur 3.12.5-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 12 12:57:31 CET 2013 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
(precise32)root@excalibur:llvm-apps# tmux -V
tmux 1.8
(precise32)root@excalibur:src# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  9 2014 23:30:55)
Included patches: 1-135
Compiled by nathan@excalibur
Huge version with X11-Athena GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What terminal emulator are you using?

Comment: Could you try *without* your fancy statusbar vim plugin?

Comment: That's it! When I uninstalled vim-powerline everything (including CtrlP) worked fine again. Thanks @romainl

Comment: I am getting the same issue with tmux (not CtrlP) even without any fancy statusbars